# How to shutdown a Windows Server 2003 machine remotely usin C#?

Tags: c#-4.0, shutdown

I want to shutdown/reboot a Windows Server 2003 machine remotely using C Sharp. I have the Administrator credntials. This app will be ran from local machines also on the LAN.

I have tried so many examples on the internet, and none appear to work :(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921905/wmi-to-reboot-remote-machine.

Answer (score 0):

Instal PsShutdown app from sysinternals [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) package and then use your code to call it like:

```
Process.Start("psshutdown.exe","-h -u "Login" -p "Password" \\PCNAMEORIP");
```

That's the simplest way i can suggest.